# Where is Visual Web Editor for JavaServer Faces on Netbeans

Tags: java, jsf, netbeans, visual-editor

I'm currently following a tutorial in a book, and it instructs to create a Java Web App with the Visual JavaServer Faces framework. The screenshot in the book shows both the JavaServer Faces framework *and* the extra Visual JavaServer Faces framework. I can't seem to find the plugin / download in the netbeans plugin page, or when I google it. Has this feature been removed?

Also [this tutorial](http://web.archive.org/web/20100405081325/http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/helloweb.html) shows this screenshot:

[image]

Have both the frameworks been integrated into one? If so, how can I access this design screen?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's the UI editor of the already since ~3 years dead and abandoned [Woodstock](https://woodstock.dev.java.net/) library . That library became an epic failure due to an bug which revealed when [Firefox 3](http://www.google.com/search?q=woodstock+firefox3) was released. It turned out that the library generates non-standards compliant Javascript which broke in the newer and more standards-compliant browsers. It was a hard smack in Woodstock's face.

Since then, users were [recommended](https://netbeans.org/community/news/show/1468.html) to migrate to [ICEfaces 1.x](http://www.icesoft.org/java/downloads/icefaces-1.8-downloads.jsf). There's an auto-migration tool for ICEfaces. ICEfaces in turn has a visual editor plugin for Netbeans. The visual editor has been removed from Netbeans since version 6.8. See also [wiki.netbeans.org/VisualWebSupport](http://wiki.netbeans.org/VisualWebSupport):

> ## VisualWebSupport
>
> #### Where can I find the Visual Web Pack with Visual Editor support for web page design?
>
> Starting from NetBeans 6.8, the Visual Web module is no longer available. No further development is planned.

Another fact is, using visual editors with code generators is strongly discouraged in the professional development world. They were often used by starters only and it produces unmaintainable and unreuseable code to a high degree. On the other hand, it makes debugging and nailing down code-level problems *much* harder for starters, because they don't understand any line of the generated code. It also unnecessarily gave JSF in general a negative imago.

If you're new to coding, don't drag'n'drop code, but just write code.

If you like to develop JSF on Netbeans, I recommend walking through the latest tutorials at [Netbeans.org](http://netbeans.org) instead (using a normal code editor!). You can find them all [here](https://netbeans.org/kb/trails/java-ee.html). With regard to learning JSF in general, start at [our JSF wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info) for a Hello World and useful links.

Comment: Thanks for this! Yeah I was just trying to follow the tutorials in the book from cover to cover, but obviously must be a little outdated! Shall refrain from drag'n'dropping in the future.

Comment: I updated the answer to include some links to better resources.