# Simple Java web application on Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, web-applications, tomcat, servlets

If we only need to graphically authorize a user,

view a few tables representation (from database),

ability to change data in the database visually

what tools to use to write such a web application that will run on Tomcat?

*What framework allows to do that in the most straightforward, easy-to-manage and elegant way?*

Comment: What **exactly** do you mean with *graphically authorize* and *change data visually*?

Comment: @BalusC I assume he means a UI for user management.

Comment: @cletus: Exist there **web** applications without an UI? :) (expect of webservices, but he didn't mention that explicitly)

Comment: @BalusC the point I think is that he doesn't want to have to code up a user admin page. He wants some scaffolding.

Comment: @cletus I just try to understand the best & most modern ways to do the job, namely which framework to go with.

Comment: Well, if you want the creme de la creme, then I would have suggested to head to [JavaEE6 with JSF2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960280/what-to-learn-for-making-java-web-applications-in-java-ee-6/1960447#1960447).

Comment: _graphically authorize_ sounds like a CAPTCHA

Answer (score 2):

I would look at [Spring Roo](http://www.springsource.org/roo) as the framework for building your app. It will allow you quick construction of most of the features you are looking for in several minutes. (or so they claim)

Answer (score 1):

There are so many elegant web frameworks available to choose from...

A [JSF](http://bg.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Faces) solution is a one suggested by the Java EE standard - if you select JSF you'll have to be more verbose in the code, but you'll have the assistance of tools such as the [Visual JSF](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/helloweb.html) designer in NetBeans. Using [JSF2](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/jsf20-intro.html) is a much better idea, IMO.

I personally recommend you to have a look at [Wicket](http://wicket.apache.org/) - it's a great Java web framework, centered around ideas such as ellegance, simplicity and usability.

There are many more great frameworks out there, but this is a start.

Comment: [No, please not Visual JSF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631130/where-is-visual-javaserver-faces-on-netbeans). It's dead, keep it dead.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that - haven't used JSF lately.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try Grails. It's Java + Groovy scripting + Spring Framework + GORM + Spring Security. Less boiler plate.

Tools: Spring Source Tool Suite (Eclipse based IDE).