# Woodstock <webuijsf:table> vanishes on page load in Chrome, Firefox and IE10+

Tags: jsp, google-chrome, internet-explorer, jsf, woodstock

Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer 10+ seem to have a bug when loading JSF pages with HTML tables generated by Woodstock `<webuijsf:table>`. The table renders, but when the page finishes loading, it vanishes.

[image]

It might be some problem with the JavaScript generated by Woodstock, or maybe with the css. How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

The Woodstock library (which was used in "Visual JSF editor" in one of the first Netbeans releases) died around 2005 and is officially abandoned by Oracle (formerly Sun) since 2006 with the *real* reason being a too overly complex and buggy JS library under the covers which was too much targeted on the MSIE browser and thus utilized the wrong "standards" which made it to broke on the "real webbrowsers". It was already somewhat buggy on Firefox2, but it broke *totally* on Firefox3 and it was exactly that which killed Woodstock. Later it turns out to work incorrectly on the upcoming webkit-based browsers as well.

Don't expect them or anyone else to fix it. Throw it away and replace by a more decent and robust component library. PrimeFaces, RichFaces, IceFaces or OpenFaces for example. The old Woodstock dev team has worked together with IceFaces on a [migration guide](http://facestutorials.icefaces.org/tutorial/woodstock/WoodstockToICEfacesPortingGuide.html).

Woodstock was a big shame. It was one of the libraries which gave JSF a bad imago.

#### See also:

- [Where is Visual Web Editor for JavaServer Faces on Netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631130/where-is-visual-web-editor-for-javaserver-faces-on-netbeans/)
- [JSF - Component Libraries, migrate or not migrate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818223/jsf-component-libraries-migrate-or-not-migrate/)