# Woodstock Java EE web application - migration to standard JSF

Tags: jsp, jsf, jakarta-ee, migration, woodstock

I am maintaing rather old web application (around ten views, including a tabbed view) which uses the Woodstock component library, and would like to migrate it to a plain JavaServer Faces.

There are two options:

- rebuild it from scratch as a separate project, or
- migrate the existing views, one by one, in the main (production) version

(of course the second option would happen in a separate version control branch, and changes will be merged to trunk only when they are tested)

I have also read [JSF - Component Libraries, migrate or not migrate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818223/jsf-component-libraries-migrate-or-not-migrate), which is related to the Woodstock component library, and gives many reasons for a migration.

Do I understand correctly that Woodstock uses JSF 1 standards for UI / code binding so I only would need to care about replacing Woodstock components with corresponding components in a JSF 1 standard implementation?

---

Additional information: the web application currently uses JavaServer Pages (JSP) for thew views.

Comment: If you're already going to rewrite the views, I'd immediately migrate JSP to Facelets as well. This easies future migration to JSF2.

Comment: @BalusC thank you for pointing to Facelets! They were not visible in the NetBeans IDE 6.5 "new file..." wizard initially - but activating the optional Facelet plugin solved this, and also added Facelet entries in web.xml.

Answer (score 2):

> Do I understand correctly that Woodstock uses JSF 1 standards for UI /
>   code binding

Actually woodstock components creates JavaScript DOM , instead of HTML unlike JSF

> I only would need to care about replacing Woodstock components with
>   corresponding components in a JSF 1 standard implementation

Correct, but need not be JSF 1

Additionally, you can use any MVC framework for that matter through which you can convert your JSP elements (woodstock components) to the ones which generate HTML