# Which jsf libraries are used in GlassFish admin console and Oracle database admin tools?

Tags: java, web-applications, jsf

I am curious what jsf libraries are used in popular admin tools like Glassfish admin console and Oracle database admin tools - I don't remember name but several years ago i used Oracle 10g database and admin and sql application was in jsf technology.

I am trying Icefaces so far and I am going to try Primefaces and Richfaces and maybe some one more?

Answer (score 1):

Glassfish admin console uses a fork of [Woodstock](http://java.net/projects/woodstock/) (the component set which first shipped with Netbeans' [Visual JSF Developer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631130/where-is-visual-javaserver-faces-on-netbeans)).

I would however not recommend this JSF component library for your projects. Rather head to more public, robust and well developed/maintained component libraries. The three you mentioned in your question, together with Tomahawk and OpenFaces, have good components.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the Oracle tools use [Oracle ADF](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/adf/overview/index-092391.html). I'm not sure about GlassFish.