# Visual Web Development IDE For JSP, JSF, and Servlets

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, jsf, netbeans

Is there any tool (IDE) that provides a visual web Development for JSP and JSF?

Before, Netbeans 5 has a visual web development plugins, but in the new version this plugins are not available I do not why?

Please, if anyone knows any visual tools or plugins that can be use it with netbeans or eclipse, provide its name and link.

Comment: As to the JSF part, read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631130/where-is-visual-javaserver-faces-on-netbeans

Comment: Search for the Web Page Editor feature from the Web Tools Platform once you've opened the Help|Install New Software option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JBoss Tools plugin for Eclipse has collection of editors for JSP, JSF etc.: http://docs.jboss.org/tools/3.2.1.GA/en/visual_web_tools_ref_guide/html/Visual_Web_Tools.html#key_features although it is relatively slow.

Comment: Isn't it just your own machine which is low on CPU power, memory space and I/O throughput?