# Netbeans 7.2.1 Visual Web Editor

Tags: java, jsf, plugins, netbeans, visual-editor

Is there some sort of Visual Web Editor for Netbeans 7.2.1 and JSF development?

Comment: I hope not.  In the version of NetBeans that I'm forced to use, the Visual Web Editor is the root of all evil!

Comment: @jahroy, I know what you mean. VWP was a very nice concept, but from NB 5.5 when it started out up till 6.7.1 when they killed it, it was deathly unreliable. It wasn't so much about Woodstock(the JSF component set that was plugged into it), although that came with it's own problems. I've lost count of the number of times I'd start NB up to continue a project and the entire UI i'd drawn up will just vanish. Several times, the designer would fall out of sync with the backing source file. It was hell.

Comment: The code generated by Visual Web is very un-maintainable. It is bloated, difficult to read and it is not portable between versions of NetBeans (at least in our case).  Also, as it says in the link from @prageeth below, the code it generates isn't guaranteed to be cross-browser compatible. I could go on and on...

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631130/where-is-visual-javaserver-faces-on-netbeans

Comment: @jahroy why root of all evil? partially generating the JSP view surely is better way than typing the tedious html tags

Comment: @shanyangqu - I can type faster than the Visual Web plugin can generate code for our app (and so can you)... it takes it about 15 minutes to even switch between pages in our app, and the IDE is rendered useless (i.e. black screen) while you wait for it to load. I'll take Vim over auto generated code any day.

Comment: @jahroy vm vs eclipse, I think the number shows the clear winner is eclipse.. you might argue the ones who uses eclipse is incompetent, or less experienced, but popularity is quite a important thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think no. Look at here to find what `Netbeans` recommends:
http://wiki.netbeans.org/VisualWebSupport

> ### Where can I find the Visual Web Pack with Visual Editor support for web page design?
>
> Starting from NetBeans 6.8, the Visual Web module is no longer available. No further development is planned. Those who want to use the Visual Web pack can use NetBeans 6.7.1 or earlier versions and get the Visual Web module from the Beta Update center.
>
> **Visual Web Documentation** for NetBeans IDE are now archived and can be downloaded as part of the NetBeans IDE 6.5 Documentation Archive. The zip file of the archive can be downloaded from http://netbeans.org/kb/archive/index.html#NetBeans_6.5_Docs_Archives
>
> ### What other options are available for developing JSF based Web apps?
>
> Developers who want to use a WYSIWYG, Visual Web-type environment that is still maintained have the following options:
>
> #### JDeveloper ADF Faces from Oracle
>
> This is a free to develop offering which provides a full featured visual JSF development environment. Oracle ADF Faces provides over 150 AJAX enabled JSF components including graphs, gauges, maps and the full set of core components as provided by the discontinued Woodstock project. For details see http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/jdev/htdocs/netbeans/jsf.html.
>
> #### IcesFaces for NetBeans
>
> IceFaces provides a similar JSF component set as Woodstock, including support for JSF 2.0. IceFaces enables users to continue using NetBeans IDE, but without a visual development environment. See http://www.icefaces.org/JForum/posts/list/16995.page for more information.
>
> #### Apache MyFaces Trinidad
>
> Apache MyFaces Trinidad is a JSF framework that has a large, enterprise quality component library, including support for JSF 2.0. Oracle'S ADF Faces is built on this framework. See http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/index.html for more information.

Comment: awh, do you know why they stopped supporting it after 6.7.1?

Comment: I can't understand why they removed it. Its discussed [here](http://netbeans-org.1045718.n5.nabble.com/Visual-Web-Is-Dead-td5592031.html) and sometimes it would help you.